How enable Content-Security-Policy in IIS
I'm trying to add a Content-Security-Policy to IIS on a Windows 2019 server. I had posted something similar but found I was going down the wrong path. In IIS, I'm going to HTTP Response Headers, clicking [Add], and putting "Content-Security-Policy" in the Name and "default-src 'self';" in the Value. But when this is saved in IIS, none of the inline scripts or styles work and the pages are a mess.
I found examples and explanations on https://content-security-policy.com that provides the description and proper syntax to allow not only inline css but scripts, images, etc. from the server:
"The default-src directive defines the default policy for fetching resources such as JavaScript, Images, CSS, Fonts, AJAX requests, Frames, HTML5 Media."
EXAMPLE DEFAULT-SRC POLICY
default-src 'self' cdn.example.com;

"default-src 'self' Allows loading resources from the same origin (same scheme, host and port)."

So, in IIS I modified the Content-Security-Policy to:
default-src 'self' www.mydomainname.net;

But my web pages are still ignoring styles and scripts!  What am I doing wrong in IIS or maybe I just don't understand yet how it's supposed to work?  It appears by adding this Content-Security-Policy value, it should allow the scripts and styles from the same server.  So, why doesn't it?


But when this is saved in IIS, none of the inline scripts or styles work and the pages are a mess.

I think you might be confusing the difference between inline and external scripts. Just refer to this doc and check their difference:

In short, the configuration you mentioned is mainly for external scripts. In this case, for inline javascript/style you need to add the following values ​​in CSP header:
script-src 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'unsafe-inline';


That will certainly make it work but this is a production system and using "unsafe-inline" kind of defeats the purpose of Content-Security-Policy doesn't it?

I agree with you, in this case, have you considered using a nonce/hash for inline scripts/styles？Or just moving all the scripts/stylesheets to external files and then loading them?

Looking at moving to separate files for most things, favoring a nonce for others.  Don't like either all that much!  ;-)

Of course, which method you use is up to you.
